# Legend shows items not in visible extent

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

I have a layer which I have set the primary symbology to 'Unique Values'. I have then used an expression which combines the values from two fields:

```
$feature.code + ' ' + $feature.name
```

The code and name fields are unique and I get the same number of items as simply classifying by just the code field or just the name field. However, when I don't use an expression only the visible items show in the legend. When I use the above expression, all of the items show in the legend, even those that aren't visible. How can I fix this?

In truth, I am only doing this so that the legend shows both the code and the name fields - so I would accept a solution that involves changing the label field (but not one by one - their are hundreds of items!)

Answer (score 1):

From the "Feature Display Options", there is a setting **Only show features visible in the map extent**. This will limit the legend to only visible items.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/work-with-legend-items.htm

Comment: I have that ticked, but it only works for me when the unique value is a field chosen by the dropdown and not an expression.